# What is the difference between the Eclipse comment types?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, comments

I am building a nice color scheme at [Eclipse Color Themes](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) (which greatly enhances the Eclipse experience, thank you very much!).  And I see that there are many different comment types.  I understand some of them, but would like to find a definitive description of the varying comment types.  Here they are:

- singleLineComment
- multiLineComment
- commentTaskTag
- javadoc
- javadocLink
- javadocTag
- javadocKeyword

If anyone knows of a link to a place that describes the important features/aspects of these different comment types, please let me know (google search was **very** unsatisfactory).  Thanks!

Comment: These are quite self-explanatory. Are you sure that you need extra info for each of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//singleLineComment

/*multiple
  line
  comment*/

//TODO commentTaskTag
//FIXME commentTaskTag
//XXX commentTaskTag

/**
 * javadoc
 *
 */

/**
 * javadocLink
 * {@link}
 */

/**
 * javadocTag
 * <a href="" />
 */

/**
 * javadocKeyword
 * @author Jagger
 */
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, Why was it censored?